# indexOutofRange BubbleSort when using inputbox

Tags: c#, bubble-sort, indexoutofrangeexception

Its been bugging me for hours because it is always returning 0 at numbers[i]  and I cant figure out the problem. code worked for a different program but I had to change it so it could have a custom array size and that's when everything went wrong.
any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

```
int[] numbers = new int[Convert.ToInt16(TxtArray.Text)];
int j = 0;
for (j = numbers.Length; j >= 0; j--)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= j - 1; i++)
    {
        string NumbersInput = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Numbers to be sorted",
                "Numbers Input", "", -1, -1);
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt16(NumbersInput);     
       //returns 0 in if statement
        if (numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1])
        {           
            int intTemp = 0;
            intTemp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
            numbers[i + 1] = intTemp;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    LstNumbers.Items.Add(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What exactly line throws exception? What is "always returning 0"?
See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The code does not make sense either, You are initializing an array from a text box, but then within your loop you are asking for numbers to sort ??? The code Smells.

Comment: I am using the Text box to allow for a custom array size and the exception is thrown at the if statemnet if (numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int sizeOfArrayInt = Convert.ToInt32(arraySize.Text);
  int[] array = new int[sizeOfArrayInt];
  string numbers = arrayValues.Text;
  string[] numbersSplit = numbers.Split(',');

  int count = 0;
  foreach (string character in numbersSplit)
  {
    int value;
    bool parse = Int32.TryParse(character, out value);
    if (value != null)
    {
      array[count] = value;
    }

    count++;
  }

  array = this.SortArray(array);
  foreach (int item in array)
  {
    this.listBox.Items.Add(item);
  }
}

private int[] SortArray(int[] arrayToSort)
{
  //int[] sortedArray = new int[arrayToSort.Length];
  int count = arrayToSort.Length;
  for (int j = count; j >= 0; j--)
  {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= j - 2; i++)
    {
      if (arrayToSort[i] < arrayToSort[i + 1])
      {
        int intTemp = 0;
        intTemp = arrayToSort[i];
        arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[i + 1];
        arrayToSort[i + 1] = intTemp;
      }
    }
  }

  return arrayToSort;
}
```

**strong text**

This I got to work as a Windows Form and the output displays in the list box as each array item or individual i iteration over the array. Of course there is no error checking. Hope that helps.

Comment: I would use List but i need to use Bubble Sort because its part of school exercise

Comment: There you go, that should work. Just make sure that your inner loop does not go outside the bounds of the array. You can do i < j -1 or i <= j - 2. Hope that helps.

Comment: As for your custom array size, just make sure when you receive your input to make your array the size of the input count and you  should be fine.

Comment: this would work in a console application but I am using a windows form application

Comment: Yes this will also work with a windows forms application. You just have to set your control values into your array, and access them like you would any collection.

Comment: made a few adjustments but now im getting 0 in my listbox for each input http://pastebin.com/NkiMkpGb

Comment: I just edited my post. I think it is easier to just show you in code. Now this works with the requirement of the array and array size values both as inputs from a windows form, although I am using windows forms C# not VB, but the same concepts apply. Also the display shows up in a listbox of items (one per line).

Comment: Thanks you helped me allot. It was bugging me for days because i have never worked with custom arrays

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the strangeness of how you are working with text boxes, your problem with throwing an exception would happen even without them because it lies here, in your inner loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= j - 1; i++)
```

Suppose that `numbers.Length == 2`.  This means that `j == 2`.  So on the first time through the outer loop, you hit the inner loop with these conditions.  The first time through, `i == 0`.  You get to the if statement:

```
if (numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1])
```

`numbers[0]` exists, and `numbers[1]` exists, so this iteration goes through fine and `i` is incremented.

Now `i == 1`. Now the loop checks its boundary condition. `i <= j - 1 == true`, so the loop continues.  Now when you hit that if statement, it tries to access `numbers[i + 1]`, i.e., `numbers[2]`, which does not exist, throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Edit:  Came back and realized that I left out the solution (to the exception, anyway).  For the bubble sort to work, your inner loop's boundary condition should be `i <= j - 2`, because `j`'s initial value is `== numbers.Length`, which is not zero-based, while array indexes are.

Second Edit: Note that **just** using a List won't actually solve this problem.  You have to use the right boundary condition.  Trying to access `list[list.Count()]` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  Just because a List will dynamically resize doesn't mean that it will somehow let you access items that don't exist.  You should always take time to check your boundary conditions, no matter what data structure you use.

Comment: There is no value for numbers.Length where this code _doesn't_ throw an IndexOutOfRangeException.  He tagged and titled the question with that exception, but until and unless we get more info from the original questioner, I suppose we won't know if he really wanted help with that or with "returning 0".

Comment: you have a point, I missed that in the title of the question :P